# dynamic sparql query with sgvizler

Tags: dynamic, sparql, sgvizler

I am trying to create a dynamic sparql query within sgvizler.

Current query is like this:

```
<div id="query1"
                data-sgvizler-query="
                    SELECT * 
                    WHERE {
                    [] <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/rankings_university> ?Name ;
                    <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/rankings_id> ?Id ;
                    <http://localhost:2020/resource/vocab/rankings_overall_score> ?overall_score ;
                    FILTER regex(?Name, '(here comes a variable')
                    }
                    LIMIT 10"
                data-sgvizler-chart="sText"
                data-sgvizler-loglevel="2"
            ></div>
```

with jquery I do the following:

```
$(function() {
$("#searchsubmit").click( function()
{
value1 = $("#uni1").val(); 
alert(value1);
sgvizler.go();
}
);
});
```

All I get is a empty page without erros while the following does work:

```
$(document).ready(sgvizler.go());
```

Any idea how I can fix this? Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is also found and answered in 
http://code.google.com/p/sgvizler/issues/detail?id=38.

Here's a new fiddle which takes input from the user builds a query and renders the results in a html container using sgvizler: http://jsfiddle.net/sgvizler/L5ztf/. See also comments in the fiddle code.

Comment: Please add everything to understand the solution to your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what your mean by that. Could you elaborate? @Emrulez's question is quite vague, and a running example is missing, so it is difficult to say what the problem is. I have provided an example which I think illustrates what (s)he is trying to do.

Comment: Your answer bascically consists of links. Wors, the jsfiddle.net will go away anytime. Future readers of your answer will not be able to understand it since relevant parts of your answer are not included here.

Comment: I will try to be more understandable: The idea was to create a dynamic sparql query with sgvizler. when on click the query should be made according to a variable. I am the one who opened issue 38 on sgvizlers page.

Comment: ... and I'm the "maker of sgvizler" :) I saw your unanswered question here and wanted to link it up to the issue at googlecode. You say that you have a problem with multiple queries and cors. Could you share the code that does not work?

Comment: when I used sgvizler with d2rq and apache I got the CORS problem on the second query here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lr6V/1/ Now I am running the file from within Joseki so no more CORS errors as it is the same domain. now my query doesnt work at all anymore but I am working on that dont think its sgvizler related. thanx again for the help.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense that one of two queries sent to the same endpoint gives the "CORS problem"; either CORS is enabled or its not. Are you sure this is the problem?

Comment: yes when I try your query with all the rest is the same the queries work. when I use my own query the second one failes with the cors error.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working:
First of all you need to use the trunk version to have support for it.
[SGvizler Trunk version](http://sgvizler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sgvizler.js)

Secondly you need to create a (jquery) function which creates the sparql query:

```
function myQuery (containerID, name) {
            var Q = new sgvizler.query(containerID),
            query = "SELECT * " + 
                    "WHERE { " +
                    "<ontology url> ?p ?Name ; " +
                    "FILTER regex(?Name, '" +  name + "')" +
                    "} " +
                    "LIMIT 10" ;
                    Q.draw({ query: query });
        }
```

Then on click the following function:

```
$(function() {
            $("#yourbutton").click( function()
                {
                    value1 = $("#inputfield").val(); 
                    myQuery('query1', value1);
                }
            );
        });
```

the HTML :

```
<div id="query1"
                data-sgvizler-chart="sText"
                data-sgvizler-loglevel="2"
            ></div>
```

This way you can create dynamic sparql queries in sgvizler I learned thanx to the maker of sgvizler.

This works great. The only problem I have is the cross-domain error when executing multiple queries.